# Configure ZF2 view_manager to load 2 separate templates maps

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I need 2 different template maps in ZF2 , one for admin and oen for front-end, currently from what I can see ZF2 merges the 2 module.config.php files that are used in the 2 modules I configured, and causes the template map I need to set for the admin, to be loaded in front module also.

the /Application module.config.php

```
...
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
...
```

the /admin module.config.php

```
...
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        ),
    ),
...
```

what should I modify so that i can load separate "view_manager" arrays for the 2 separate modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you can explain why you are trying to achieve this. As i can see you are trying to have a different layout for admin. Maybe you want to take a look at this module which can already do what you are trying https://github.com/zf-commons/zfcadmin. This module has a layut setup for the admin route.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about the existence of zfcadmin wich is already configured. Don't know how to explain more why i`m trying to achive this, except I want the admin module i`ve create to have a different layout, but didn't quite succeeded because any try to modify the layout for the admin module i`ve created will also change the layout for the main module (Application). After some research, i`ve seen that zend will merge the module.config files for all modules, and didn't find a way to separate the layout part.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem. I took the approach which is proposed in the below module

https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to ZF2 and I too was looking for an answer on how to have a completely different template for a dashboard, admin and front end.

I used `EdpModuleLayouts` as suggested here and in many other posts. This solved one aspect of the problem. The layout. I was now able to provide different layouts for the same template which would work well if I were using the same template or wanted to prove a different layout for say forgotten password, registration or a login. But I didn't. I needed a whole different set of folders, css files etc. At this point I could have just nested all templates in to a template folder and pointed the links in the layout files to the appropriate folders. But I didn't want this either.

I also included the `zfc-admin` module into my app which gave me a clue as to the other aspect which is to provide a different source directly for files. (Uninstalled afterward)

So adding by adding the following to my `module_name/config/module.config.php`

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../view'
        ),
),
```

Enabling `EdpModuleLayouts` in `application.config.php` and adding the code below to the Application `module.config.php`

```
'module_layouts' => array(
    'Application' => 'layout/layout',
    'Dashboard' => 'layout/dashboard',
    'Admin' => 'layout/admin',
),
```

This is probably not the best way to do it but it worked. The only issue I could really see with doing it this way is that EdpModuleLayouts wants to pull all the layouts from the `Application/view/layout` folder. It did however allow me to keep all my module template files in the view section of the module being worked on.